# CSS selector for shadow root or all top level elements in shadow root

Tags: css, html, shadow-dom

I need a selector for usage in css inside a shadow root, which selects all children (but not grand children) of the shadow root, no matter what tag they are and without giving them an ID.

In the example below, SPAN,A,P and DIV should get a red border, but SPAN IN DIV not.

```
<my-element>
  #shadow-root
    <span>SPAN</span>
    <a>A</a>
    <p>P</p>
    <div>
      DIV
      <span>SPAN IN DIV</span>
    </div>
    <style>
      :root>*{border:1px red solid;}
    </style>
</my-element>
```

I hoped, the `:root`-Selector would do the job inside of a shadow dom, but thats not the case.

It would also be a possible solution if someone shows how to set an ID on the shadow root.

**Update:**

Tried using `#shadow-root > *` as selector:

seems not to work. Probably it is just google chrome developer tools visualizing the shadow root element like that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use this selector: `:host > *`

The `:host` selector is described in https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping/#host-selector

```js
document.querySelector( 'my-element' )
  .attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
  .innerHTML = `
    <span>SPAN</span>
    <a>A</a>
    <p>P</p>
    <div>
      DIV
      <span>SPAN IN DIV</span>
    </div>
    <style>
      :host>*{border:1px red solid;}
    </style>`
```

```html
<my-element>
</my-element>
```

`:host` may also hold a compound selector, which must be places in brackets. E.g. `:host([foo=bar])` selects a host element which has attribute `foo` set to `bar`.

Comment: Thank you! Does that also work, when mode is 'closed' (of course from inside the shadow dom)?

Comment: Great, you helped me alot. I knew about the :host selector, but I did not expect it to work in that situation (thought it would only bring me outside of that scope but not back in...)

Comment: I will even accept it as answer - I was just still verifying (interleaved with drinking tea)

Comment: As a follow up: I converted your answer into a jsfiddle and added a more specific style rule (attribute selector on host) and then it does not work anymore. Any explanation? https://jsfiddle.net/ex8qam0p/2/ - Does :host actually select the shadow root or the host element?

Comment: @Alfi use brackets to enclose the attribute: ':host( [foo="bar"] )'

Comment: I was asked in person. Let me add some comments here.
`:host[foo=bar]` is invalid syntax. That should be `:host([foo=bar])` - https://jsfiddle.net/ex8qam0p/3/.
See https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping/#host-selector for details.
`:host` actually select the shadow host. A shadow root is never selected by any CSS selector because a shadow root is not an element. That is by design.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I was not aware of that it was incorrect syntax. Intuitively I came from #id[foo=bar] and thus thought it were :host[foo=bar]. But the specification seems to be clear about that.

Comment: it seems `:host` is not actually equivalent to `:root` in that I can't define custom properties in it and have them show up anywhere under the shadow root. (I get "no defined" when I inspect to see why my CSS is not working in grandchild elements under the shadow root)

Answer (score 2):

we can use the shadow() method from cypress. you can use the **get('selector before the shadow-root')** method then **shadow()** method and use the **find('locator')** till your control/elements and at last you invoke the actual method e.g. click() or type() or select('index') on that control/element. Also you can use **{force:true}** aswell.

```
cy.get("mc-select[name='taxTypeCodes']").shadow().find('div.mc-component-template ').find('div').find('label.mc-input__container').find('div.mc-input__field').find('select').select('IN3',{force:true})
```

For more details please refer-[cypress-shadow-dom](https://testersdock.com/cypress-shadow-dom/)