# CSS selector for child of shadow root

Tags: html, css, shadow-dom

```html
<curie-image id="DynamicImage1">
    #shadow-root
        <img alt="No Image" style="width:100%;height:100%" src="data:image;base64, ...">
</curie-image>
```

I am trying to access the `img` element above to set its `object-fit` attribute. I do not have access to the underlying JavaScript, so cannot set the `part` attribute of the shadow root's children, and so [Styling children of shadow dom ::part element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67940807/style-children-of-shadow-dom-part-element) will not work in my case. Also, I believe [using the `:host()` selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42627939/css-selector-for-shadow-root-or-all-top-level-elements-in-shadow-root) will not work in this case, as the selector needs to be ["evaluated in the context of a shadow tree"](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping/#selectordef-host) in order to work.

Given these constraints, is there any CSS selector which will select a child of my shadow root, from a context outside of the shadow root?

For some reason, a simple selector for `img` in the global CSS file does select the `img` element in this shadow root, even though it [supposedly should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71035789/select-element-in-shadow-root-with-css-only) match all such elements, even if they are within a shadow root - see CSS and resulting style below (note that the `object-fit` attribute has not been set for the `img` element).

```css
...
img { 
  object-fit: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: you are required to post code in a snippet that shows your issue in order to help others to understand and help you by editing your code.

Comment: Post the code where you say _"For some reason, a simple selector for img in the global CSS file does select the img element"_ The whole point of shadowDOM is to not let global CSS style content...

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Have updated the question. Yes, I thought that might be the case - the shadow root is an encapsulation mechanism intended to prevent the children of it being accessed. To explain why I need to do this: I am working with a development framework for which there is only a limited set of elements that are bind-able to the back end. I am therefore forced to use this `curie-image` as a dynamically settable image, but the `img` it contains has undesirable default properties to do with sizing, which I would like to change if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an *open* shadowRoot, you have JavaScript access with

`.querySelector("curie-image").shadowRoot.querySelector("img").style.objectFit="none"`

But that is ***ductaping*** styles.

#### Dive to all <img>

You could dive into all IMGs with:

(will not *dive into* `closed` shadowRoots)

```js
const shadowDive = (
  el,
  selector,
  match = (el, root) => {
    if(root.localName == "curie-image"){
      el.style.ObjectFit="none";
    }
  },
  root = el.shadowRoot || el
) => {
  root.querySelector(selector) && match(root.querySelector(selector), root);
  [...root.querySelectorAll("*")].map(el => shadowDive(el, selector, match));
}

shadowDive(document.body, 'img[style]' );
```

*disclaimer*: untested code snippet

---

Preferable you will want to change the `curie-image` source code and introduce HTML `<slot>` and CSS `::part` (you can also dynamically wack on with JS)

#### Note:

**Web Components can do *Client Side*, what no Framework can with a Component:**

```js
customElements.define( "curied-image" , 
  class extends customElements.get("curie-image") {

  connectedCallback(){
    super.connectedCallback(); // call original <curie-image> connectedCallback
    
    // now do what you want with 'this' <curied-image> Web Component here

  }

});
```

See my Dev.To posts:

- [How to cheat with Web Components](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/how-to-cheat-with-web-components-295o)
- [More Wordle = Mordle, extending Josh his Web Components](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/more-wordle-mordle-extending-josh-his-web-components-4li)

note: You *can* extend `closed` Web Components; but you can still **not** access its shadowRoot.